# How to change variable from within qmake replace function

Tags: function, configuration, qt5, qmake

I am trying to create a custom **qmake** "replace function" that basically appends some stuff to the `INCLUDEPATH` variables like so:

```
defineReplace(myFunc) {
    lo=$$lower($$1)
    INCLUDEPATH += /someDir/libs/lib$${lo}
    message("| INCLUDEPATH A: " $${INCLUDEPATH})
    return (true)
}
```

However when I run this function with a parameter and then print out `INCLUDEPATH` variables like this:

```
$$myFunc(whatever)
message("| INCLUDEPATH B: " $${INCLUDEPATH})
```

I get the following in the log:

```
Project MESSAGE: | INCLUDEPATH A: /someDir/libs/libwhatever
Project MESSAGE: | INCLUDEPATH B:
```

This indicates that the function works, but somehow the changes made to the `INCLUDEPATH` variable are not preserved.

I want to know how I can get the behavior I expected (`INCLUDEPATH` maintains the changes made to it after I run my function). *How can I do that?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a call to `export`. From the [qmake manual](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-test-function-reference.html#export-variablename):

> export(variablename)
>
> Exports the current value of variablename from the local context of a function > to the global context

So your code should be

```
defineReplace(myFunc) {
    lo=$$lower($$1)
    INCLUDEPATH += /someDir/libs/lib$${lo}
    message("| INCLUDEPATH A: " $${INCLUDEPATH})

    export(INCLUDEPATH)                            # <-- This is new

    return (true)
}
```